# R: randomly sample a nonzero element in a vector and replace other elements with 0

Tags: r, vector, sample

Suppose I have a vector

`vec <- c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2)`

How do I random sample a nonzero element and turn other elements into 0?

Suppose the element sampled was vec[2], then the resulting vector would be

`vec <- c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)`

I know that I can sample the indice of one nonzero element by sample(which(vec != 0), 1), but I am not sure how to proceed from that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the code below

```
> replace(0 * vec, sample(which(vec != 0), 1), 1)
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
```

where

- `which` returns the indices of non-zero values
- `sample` gives a random index
- `replace` replaces the value to `1` at the specific index

Answer (score 0):

Watch out for `sample`'s behavior if `which` returns only 1 value:

```
> vec <- c(rep(0, 9), 1)
> sample(which(vec != 0), 1)
 [1] 4
```

This preserves the vector value (instead of turning it to `1`) and guards against vectors with only one nonzero value using `rep` to guarantee `sample` gets a vector with more than one element:

```
vec[-sample(rep(which(vec != 0), 2), 1)] <- 0
```